# delayed job not performed after enqueued

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a custom job class:

```
class RemoteServiceNotifierJob < Struct.new(:object_id, :object_class, :action)

  def self.enqueue(object_id, object_class, action)
    job = new(object_id, object_class, action)

    Delayed::Job.enqueue job, queue: 'remote_service_notifier'
  end

  def perform
    RestClient.post(url, params, content_type: 'application/json') { |response, request, result, &block|
      unless response.code == 201
        raise RemoteServiceNotifierError
      end
    }
  end

end
```

When I run at rails console:

```
RemoteServiceNotifierJob.enqueue id, 'ServiceRequest', 'update'
```

The delayed job is inserted, and then deleted immediately right after.

I have set delayed job config to:

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
```

But the delayed job never gets performed.

Comment: for some reason, after I redeploy, everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, after I redeploy, everything is working perfectly.